# How to dockerize Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I want to dockerize my Spring Boot Project.
In eclipse, I have already created a Dockerfile (after creating the application jar file) like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar"]
```

[image]

Now what should I do to be able to dockerize?

Comment: Build the image and run the container?

Comment: Ditch your docker file and just do `mvn spring-boot:build-image` and sit back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your app listens on port 80

```sh
docker build -t <your-app-name> .
docker run -d -p 80:80 <your-app-name>
```

Comment: ok, but in your-app-name I have to write the name that is in the artefactId that I put in the pom ??

Comment: any name you would like. In the first command you are crating the docker image and giving it the name you desire, In the second command you run the docker container and here you need to use the same name you gave before

Comment: Ok, but now if i try to run the first command I get this error: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount912678100/target: no such file or directory

Comment: docker build -t device-fixer:0.1 .

Comment: The error is saying that the target directory on your machine does not exist. When you run `COPY ${JAR_FILE} device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar` (that gets converted into `COPY target/device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar device-fixer-1.2.1.jar.jar`) docker the first path is referring to a path on your machine. So its looks like you have no target directory. Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233278/discussion-between-guidop21-and-matteo-zanoni).

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this in the future the issue was that `target/` was in the `.dockerignore` file. Removing it fixed the problem

Comment: And if i want to create a docker-compose?? How Can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Create files that are named as `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` under project root directory.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
COPY /target/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '1'
    services:
        app:
            build:
                context: "./"
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            container_name: 'app-name'
            hostname: app-name
            ports:
                - '8080:8080'
```

Run `docker-compose up -d` command under root directory to create an image and run your application on localhost:8080